# Can't use android:sharedUserId right

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I know that similar questions have been posted before, but I believe there has not been an answer for my exact use case.

I have a trial and a full version of my Android app. When the user buys the full version, both versions should share their settings. Changes in one app should show up in the other app as well. When one app is un-installed, the settings shall be preserved for the other app. It's not a one-time import because the user might not uninstall the trial app and could even continue using it.

Both apps use **the same shared user id** and run in **the same process**. However, when I call getFilesDir(), the directory returned contains the package name of the app, so the directories for storing files used by the two apps differ. How can I have both apps use the exact same file without using external storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I have both apps use the exact same file without using external storage?

That will not meet your objective:

> When one app is un-installed, the settings shall be preserved for the other app

Given that objective, by definition, you cannot be using a single file that will be removed on uninstall, as if the user uninstalls that app, the other app is broken.

Your choices are:

1. Use external storage, specifically *not* `getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()`, or
2. Have each app maintain its own copy of the file, using some mechanism to keep the changes in sync, or
3. Switch to in-app purchases, so you do not have separate free/paid apps, or
4. Abandon your "both apps should share their settings" objective

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I will pursue option (2).

Answer (score 0):

You need to save those preferences either to a file or database if you want them to remain after the process containing all the components close.

A quick way, if you have this in your control, is to change all the uid's for your applications to the same and use the file api's for reading and writing from a file or the database.  Using a database is just a step away from using a content provider though... which is probably the correct most solution.